# Google Maps Route inside C#

Tags: c#, api, google-maps

guys, I tryed two different methods to get a route inside Google Maps in C#, based on two points that I know the coordinates. However, I can't do that. I can draw a straight line that connects both points (using Polygons), but drawing a route is still an issue. I'm also gonna ask if the fact that I use no Google API KEY is relevant in this case. Here I have the method that I tryed to use without sucess:

```
 public void CreateRoute(double lat, double lng)
    {
        if (BooleanCreateRoute == true)
        {
            switch (RouteCounter)
            {
                case 0:
                    RouteCounter++;
                    inicialPoint = new PointLatLng(lat, lng);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    finalPoint = new PointLatLng(lat, lng);
                    GDirections direection;
                    var RouteDirection = GMapProviders.GoogleMap.GetDirections(out direction, inicialPoint, finalPoint, false, false, false, false, false);
                    GMapRoute route = new GMapRoute(direction.Route, "route that I'm testing");
                    GMapOverlay MyOverlay = new GMapOverlay();
                    MyOverLay.Routes.Add(route);
                    map.Overlays.Add(MyOverLay);
                    map.Zoom = map.Zoom + 1;
                    map.Zoom = map.Zoom - 1;
                    RouteCounter = 0;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

The idea is to use this method two times in a row, first passing the inicialPoint coordinates (and executing case 0) and then passing the finalPoint cordinates (executing case 1). Is important to say that this is just a piece of some bigger code, so "BooleanCreateRoute" is just a parameter that I use to control if I can or can't get a route, "RouteCounter" is a global integer variable that I use to define which "case" do I execute, "inicialPoint" and "finalPoint" are global PointLatLng variables (I intend to draw a route between these points).

The "GDirections" thing is something that I saw in one spanish tutorial on YouTube. Unfortunately, I always get an error "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" when it comes to my RouteDirection. If anyone can solve this problem, I'll be extremely glad.

Thanks for the attention!

Comment: Did you try to add a second layer and put each route on a different layer?

Comment: Do you apply an API key somewhere? It is mandatory since July 2018.